# Unable to fetch values from an input element in Bootstrap's popover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fetch values from some input fields that are placed in a Bootstrap Popover. But I get empty string.

Complexity: There is a button within a form, when you click this button a popover appears with 2 input fields and a button. I want to capture the values of these 2 fields when we click the button. If I put these fields in a form, then it would become nested forms.

Following is my code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger popper hyperlink" data-toggle="popover">Trial</button>
<div class="popper-content hide">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id='urlLabel' placeholder="URL Label">
   <input type="text" class="form-control url" id='url' placeholder="Complete URL">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block urlDetails">Done</button>
</div>
```

My way of fetching values

```
$('.urlDetails').click(function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  console.log($('#urlLabel').val());
  console.log($('#url').val());
})
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/7d9bboyL/) covering the above case.

Comment: If you are getting value for `$('#url')`, but not for `$('#urlLabel')`, then, it is because you have misspelled `urlLabel` in your jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, I used the right name but I don't get values for both the fields. I just get 'clicked' in console.

Comment: Hmm... From what we have, it must work. The problem might be somewhere else. Can you create jsfiddle with your actual code that replicates the problem?

Comment: Yes, I've added the fiddle. Here it is again - https://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/7d9bboyL/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try following code:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.urlDetails', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        console.log($('.popover-content').find('#urlLabel').val());
        console.log($('.popover-content').find('#url').val());
    })
});
```

Comment: It is working Thanks. But, how is it   $('.popover-content')    while my class name is    $('.popper-content')    .

Comment: jQuery popover wraps all the html in div with class 'popover-content'. All you need to do is find your textbox inside this div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.urlDetails').click(function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  console.log($('#urlLabel').val());
  console.log($('#url').val());
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger popper hyperlink" data-toggle="popover">Trial</button>
<div class="popper-content hide">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id='urlLabel' placeholder="URL Label">
   <input type="text" class="form-control url" id='url' placeholder="Complete URL">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block urlDetails">Done</button>
</div>
```

Here is a working code

Comment: I have edited the spell mistake. However, your answer is a flat HTML code. As I said for me those fields appear in a popover after DOM. Try to add the following code along with Bootstrap library.
    $('.popper').popover({
      placement: 'auto',
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
      }
  });