# jQuery Nested function variable scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot get a nested variable value to populate outside a nested function within a button's click event function even though I believe I am using a global variable.

What am I doing wrong to pull value into a console log outside the nested function?

I am creating a shopping cart utilizing jquery pop-up with ajax and php. I am able to add items to the cart as well as add a name & email input field.

When I go to console log in Chrome for the focusout event for the fields they show the values but when trying to use a Checkout button, I am not able to pass the data within the Checkout click outside of a nested function even with a global variable.

--JS--

```
   var formname;
$(document).ready(function() {
...
    $(document).on('click', '#check_out_cart', function(){            

          $('#cart-popover').popover({
                html : true,
                container: 'body',
                content:function(){
                  return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
                }
          });      

           $(document).on('click', '#cart-popover', function(){    
                  $('input#namef').focus();                   
          });

            $('input#namef').on('focusout', function(){                  
                    formname= $('input#namef').val();                         
                    console.log(formname);
            });

            var scart_add = $("input[name='scart_add']").val();
            console.log("Scart value is "+scart_add);
            console.log("Name is "+formname);
            ...

    });
});
```

--HTML--

```
 <div class="container">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                    </button>                    
                  </div>

                  <div id="navbar-cart" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li>
                        <a id="cart-popover" class="btn" data-placement="bottom" title="Shopping Cart">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart-2x"></span>
                          <span class="badge"></span>
                          <span class="total_price">$ 0.00</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>                  
                </div>
              </nav>    
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
              <span id="cart_details"></span>
              <div>
                <form method="POST">
                  Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="namef" >&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Email:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="emailf" >&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input type="hidden" name="scart_add" value="1" /><br><br>
</div>
<div align="right">                  
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="check_out_cart">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Check out
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="clear_cart">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Clear
                  </button>                
</div>
</form>            
</div>
</div>
<div id="display_item">
</div>
...
</div>
```

I am expecting the value from the input#namef text to appear in the console.log ...formname variable but it just shows as "".

Comment: Can you provide any snippets ?, Its really very weird you are calling `focusout` in `click`

Comment: As a general rule you should not be nesting event handlers. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The event for `focusout` isn't added to the `input` until you `click` the button:
Also, I don't know if it is how you copied and pasted your HTML and Javascript, but it was throwing errors when I put it into a fiddle.

Move this outside of the button click handler as Rory pointed out:

```
var formname;
$(document).ready(function() {
        //Now focusout handler is added on DOM Ready instead of when you click the button
        $('input#namef').on('focusout', function(){                  
               formname= $('input#namef').val();                         
               console.log(formname);
         });

         $(document).on('click', '#check_out_cart', function(){            

            var scart_add = $("input[name='scart_add']").val();
            console.log("Scart value is "+scart_add);
            console.log("Name is "+formname);

         });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hqgv7zsa/

Comment: This works if I remove the style="display: none" from the div but the shopping cart is initially not visible until the #cart-popover button is click to put it into a modal/pop-up. (See above for more context after edit)... The popover function is part of a bootstrap JS

Answer (score 0):

This is a race condition, of sorts.

- On `document.ready` event, you are setting a click event handler
- Inside the click handler, you are setting the `focusout` event handler
- Since the click handler is still executing,
  immediately, the code runs to show value of scart and formname.

> At that time, `formname` is still empty because the current function
>   (click event handler) is still executing, and the focusout event, even
>   if it fires, will fire after that code is executed.

---

*You should move the `focusout` handler declaration code outside of the click handler code, which will then set both handlers on document.ready() event.*

**Here's a breakdown of what's happening and when:**

```
var formname; 
$(document).ready(function() {
```

This fires when DOM is loaded (`document.ready` event)

```
    $(document).on('click', '#check_out_cart', function(){
```

This fires when user clicks on some element with ID `check_out_cart`

```
        $('input#namef').on('focusout', function(){
```

This event handler is only being set once user clicks on cart, **but it is not yet executed!**

```
                formname= $('input#namef').val();                         
                console.log(formname);
        });
```

This code fires once the event handler has been set for `focusout`, but still has not executed. Even if a `focusout` event is fired, it will only execute when the current function exits.

```
        var scart_add = $("input[name='scart_add']").val();
        console.log("Scart value is "+scart_add);
```

Correctly, you will see that `formname` is empty at this point.

```
        console.log("Name is "+formname);
        ...
    });
});
```

Hope this explains the flow you're seeing;

Quick fix as in Ryan Wilson's answer, move the focusout handler declaration to the scope of the document.ready handler, outside the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution from [Unable to fetch values from an input element in Bootstrap's popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384903/unable-to-fetch-values-from-an-input-element-in-bootstraps-popover),  I was able to adjust my JS code to fetch the values with a .find within the .popover-content class that was added by the popover JS.

```
    var formname; 
    var formemail;       
$(document).ready(function() {
          //shopping cart

          /*load functions*/
          load_product();
          load_cart_data();

          $('#cart-popover').popover({
                html : true,
                container: 'body',
                content:function(){                  
                  return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
                }
          });

          $(document).on('click', '#cart-popover', function(){    
                  $('input#namef').focus();                   
          });

          $(document).on('focusout', '#namef', function(){
                formname = $('.popover-content').find('#namef').val();                
          });

          $(document).on('focusout', '#emailf', function(){                
                formemail = $('.popover-content').find('#emailf').val();
          });

           $(document).on('click', '#check_out_cart', function(){
                  var scart_add = $("input[name='scart_add']").val();
                  var nameval = $("input#namef").val();
                  alert("Scart value is "+scart_add);
                  alert("Name is "+formname);            
                  alert("Email is "+formemail); 

          });
});
```